# Can you please help me identify these components and state their function?

Tags: batteries, sensor, components

[image]

Can you please help me identify these components and state their function?
These were taken from the inside of a digital thermometer.

Comment: LCD clips screws battery sound-maker cover and something else on the left ...

Comment: @Trevor That little thing to the left is one of those silicone rubber buttons, I think.

Comment: @jonk ya you are probably right. Fuzzy picture though.

Comment: @Trevor Translucent silicon rubber buttons are inherently fuzzy-looking. ;)

Comment: no chance of getting it work again but all it needed was a new coin cell that is bulged but the bottom piezo disc is still intact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the baby got your digital thermometer.

[image]

> Can you please help me identify these components and state their function?

- LCD (liquid crystal display) provides a human readable display of the temperature in adequate light.
- Metallic contacts provide connections - most likely from the circuit board to the battery (see below).
- Screw(s) **skru**ː *noun*, a short, slender, metal pin with a raised helical thread running around it and a slotted head, used to join things together by being rotated so that it pierces wood or other material and is held tightly in place.
- Probably the push-button membrane which is designed to bridge out contacts on the PCB to turn on and off the thermometer.
- A 'coin' cell to power the electronics.
- A piezo buzzer used to generate an audible 'beep' when a stable measurement has been obtained.
- The battery cap.

Check the baby's diaper / nappy for the rest of the parts including the sensor and PCB.

Comment: Hahaha, I am thinking what if she really find a PCB in the diaper.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it is correct, thanks.